# Get nested xml element with php

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I'm trying for a few days now but i can't find the right code.. I'm so desperate so i hope somebody can help me..

This is my XML code:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<addon id="repo.name" name="Repo name" version="1.1.0.1" provider-name="provider name">
    <extension point="xbmc.addon.repository" name="repo name">
        <info compressed="false">http://data.com/addons.xml</info>
        <checksum>http://data.com/addons.xml.md5</checksum>
        <datadir zip="true">http://data.com/files</datadir>
    </extension>
    <extension point="xbmc.addon.metadata">
    <description lang="en">bla bla</description>
    <disclaimer lang="en">bla 2 bla 2</disclaimer>
    <language></language>
    <platform>all</platform>
    <license>GNU GENERAL PUBLIC LICENSE. Version 2, June 1991</license>
 </extension>
</addon>
```

How do i get the following value in PHP:

```
<extension point="xbmc.addon.metadata">
       <description lang="en">bla bla</description> <---- This one
```

i Tried thing like foreach loops and xpath but nothing gets me string with: "bla bla"

```
 foreach ($success->summary as $success2) {

                         echo $success2['lang'];

             foreach ($success2->attributes()['lang'] as $success3) {


                 print_r($success3->summary);


foreach($xml->xpath('extension/@point') as $link) { echo $link['platform']; echo "\n"; }
```

I hope someone can help me so i can finish my litle project

Edit:

Thanks @Mega6382 for the help.

But when i try to get multiple languages from the description it wont work:

XML is like:

```
   <extension point="xbmc.addon.metadata">
        <description lang="en">en bla bla</description>

    <description lang="nl">Dutch desc</description>
    <description lang="be">English desc</description>
    <description>Standard desc</description>

 </extension>
```

But when i try to get to Dutch and English lang i only get the english description (and when i move nl above en i get only the nl description..)

Php code:

```
<?php   

$xml = simplexml_load_string ('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<addon id="repo.name" name="Repo name" version="1.1.0.1" provider-name="provider name">
    <extension point="xbmc.addon.repository" name="repo name">
        <info compressed="false">http://data.com/addons.xml</info>
        <checksum>http://data.com/addons.xml.md5</checksum>
        <datadir zip="true">http://data.com/files</datadir>
    </extension>
    <extension point="xbmc.addon.metadata">
        <description lang="en">en bla bla</description>

    <description lang="nl">Dutch desc</description>
    <description lang="de">German desc</description>
    <description>Standard desc</description>

 </extension>
</addon>');

foreach($xml->extension as $extension)
{
    if(isset($extension->description))
    {
        if($extension->description['lang'] == 'en')
        {
            echo $extension->description;
        }
        if($extension->description['lang'] == 'nl')
        {
            echo $extension->description;
        }

    }
}




            ?>
```

Comment: Can you please post what have you tried

Comment: I deleted the rest, the last thing i tried: 
`foreach($xml->xpath('extension/@point') as $link) { 
    echo $link['platform'];
    echo "\n"; 
}`

But i even won't get the value of platform..

Comment: @Arjanth Just remove the `continue;` and it should work.

Comment: @mega6382 nop.. Still won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string ('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<addon id="repo.name" name="Repo name" version="1.1.0.1" provider-name="provider name">
    <extension point="xbmc.addon.repository" name="repo name">
        <info compressed="false">http://data.com/addons.xml</info>
        <checksum>http://data.com/addons.xml.md5</checksum>
        <datadir zip="true">http://data.com/files</datadir>
    </extension>
    <extension point="xbmc.addon.metadata">
    <description lang="en">bla bla</description>
    <disclaimer lang="en">bla 2 bla 2</disclaimer>
    <language></language>
    <platform>all</platform>
    <license>GNU GENERAL PUBLIC LICENSE. Version 2, June 1991</license>
 </extension>
</addon>');

$description = [];
$descriptionEng = null;
foreach($xml->extension as $extension)
{
    if(isset($extension->description))
    {
        if($extension->description['lang'] == 'en')
        {
            $descriptionEng = $extension->description;
            continue;
        }
        $description[] = $extension->description;
    }
}

var_dump($description);
```

This will go through all of the `<extension>` tags and will check for and store the `<description>` tags in the `$description` array. you can access one of them by something like `print_r($description[0])`

**Edit:** `$descriptionEng` will contain the `<description>` tag with `lang=en` while `$description` will contain the rest of them.

**Edit 2:**
Try the following to get descriptions from the same extension.

```
$descriptionEng = null;
$descriptionDe = null;
$descriptionNl = null;
foreach($xml->extension as $extension)
{
    if(isset($extension->description))
    {
        foreach($extension->description as $description)
        {
            if($description['lang'] == 'en')
            {
                $descriptionEng = $description;
            }
            elseif($description['lang'] == 'de')
            {
                $descriptionDe = $description;
                continue;
            }
            elseif($description['lang'] == 'nl')
            {
                $descriptionNl = $description;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Wow, that worked... Do you also now how to get only the lang=en description. And if the lang=en doesn't excist use the description without lang: <description>bla bla</description>

Comment: Thanks! @Mega6382 +1

Comment: One thing: `       if($extension->description['lang'] == 'en')
        {
            $descriptionEng = $extension->description;
   continue;
        }
  if($extension->description['lang'] == 'nl')
        {
            $descriptionNl = $extension->description;
   continue;
        }` Why can i not save multiple lanuages?

Comment: `object(SimpleXMLElement)#5 (0) { } object(SimpleXMLElement)#4 (5) { ["@attributes"]=> array(1) { ["lang"]=> string(2) "en" } [0]=> string(10) "en bla bla" [1]=> string(10) "nl bla bla" [2]=> string(10) "en bla bla" [3]=> string(10) "no bla bla" } ` Only Lang['en'] works.. Lang['nl'] not

Comment: Now i only get the lang value's: (nl en de) `$descriptionDe = $description['lang'];`
I want the data inside the description.

Comment: @Arjanth sorry check again.